# Click event in jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I got a div with a default class of 'unlock' and text named 'UNLOCK'.
when i click it, it says 'UNLOCK' and at the same time remove the class 'unlock' and add a class of 'lock'.

html

```
<div class='unlock'>UNLOCKED</div>
```

this worked

```
$('.unlock').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('unlock').addClass('lock').text('LOCKED');
});
```

but this did not worked

```
$('.lock').click(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('lock');
});
```

And I'm not sure why it didn't work coz the class was already replaced so it should work right?

Basically, all I want is like a toggle functionality that when you first click it should say LOCKED. then when you click it again, it should say UNLOCKED.

I tried the `toggle()` but it didn't work also or I just don't know how to implement it. So any ideas how I can make this functionality work?

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhdt4bto/)

Comment: Since the nature of the element has to be changed bases on the updated status... you need to use event delegation

Comment: i c. now i get it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call. So, `$('.lock')` doesn't exists when event binding is performed thus event handler is not binded.

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', ".lock", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('lock');
});
```

Comment: i c. now i understand what happens. thanks much